# Is os.path.join necessary?

Tags: python, filepath

Currently I use `os.path.join` almost always in my django project for cross OS support; the only places where I don't currently use it are for template names and for URLs. So in situations where I want the path `'/path/to/some/file.ext'` I use `os.path.join('path', 'to', 'some', 'file.ext')`.

However I just tested my project on windows to see whether that worked fine / was necessary and it seems windows will happily accept `'/'` or `'\\'` (or `'\'` when working outside of python), and as all UNIX systems all use `'/'` it seems like there is no reason to ever use `'\\'`, in which case is it necessary to use `os.path.join` anywhere?

Is there a situation in which adding a `'/'` or using `posixpath` will cause problems on certain operating systems (not including XP or below as they are no longer officially supported)? If not I think I will just use `posixpath` or adding a `'/'` for joining variables with other variables or variables with strings and not separate out string paths (so leave it as `'/path/to/some/file.ext'`) unless there is another reason for me to not do that other than it breaking things.

To avoid this being potentially closed as primarily-opinion based I would like to clarify that my specific question is whether not using `os.path.join` will ever cause a python program to not work as intended on a supported operating system.

Comment: Although perhaps too esoteric for an answer, using a hard-coded path separator will cause non-portability with RISC OS .. (and [there are ports](https://www.python.org/download/other/) to such)

Comment: Is RISC OS compatible with django, nginx, supervisor and various django libraries? If not I won't need to worry about it on this project, but if it is it may be worth me thinking about.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Microsoft Windows API doesn't care whether you use `/` or `\`, so it's normally fine to use either as a separator on Windows.  However, command line ("DOS box" - `command.com` or `cmd.exe`) commands generally require `\` in paths (`/` is used to flag command options in these native Windows shells).  So, for example, if you build a command line in Python and fire off a shell to execute the command, you'll generally need to use the `\` separator on Windows.

One other case is covered in `Lib/macpath.py`:  there `sep` is set to `:` (a colon), catering to older Macintosh systems.  I believe that's the only system Python has ever run on that doesn't accept `/` as a separator.

EDIT:  [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a long account of Windows naming rules.  Don't blame me ;-)

Comment: In cmd.exe what kind of commands will not work? Because I just tested cd './test/test' and 'python .test/manage.py' and they both worked fine.

Comment: Try harder - you'll find plenty that won't work ;-)  For example, `dir ./misc` if you're currently in a directory that has a `misc` sub-directory.  You'll get error `Invalid switch - "misc".`.  For an exact accounting of all cases, you'll have to ask Microsoft :-(

Comment: Okay thank you! I tested 'cd' and 'python' immediately as those were the ones that I primarily used and assumed that / actually did work.

Comment: For non-native commands (like `python`), the shell doesn't care, because the shell isn't interpreting the commands, just passing the strings on to the program you're running (the first thing named on the command line).  The problems generally occur with commands implemented **by** the shell, like `dir`.  And `cd`.  But, this being Windows, nothing is consistent :-(

Comment: Note that if you may need to process long paths (using the `\\?\` format) you must use backslashes.

Comment: Is that still true for windows network share paths?  I thought windows explicitly only allows \\networklocation\path\

Comment: @MarcelWilson - I don't know, I never tried it.  How about you try it and report back? :-)

Comment: Windows may not care, but most commands do, they interpret / as a parameter | or switch

Answer (score 4):

If you are presenting a filename to a user for any reason, it's better if that filename follows the usual OS conventions.

Windows has been able to use the `/` for path separators for as long as there have been paths - this was a DOS feature.

Comment: In this case it is on a website so the only time paths will be presented are URL paths which will always use a / so I am fine to just always use /? And thanks for the information on / always being supported.